# Django autocompete_light submit programmatically

Tags: javascript, django, django-autocomplete-light

Hi Djangonauts / autocomplete_light users,

I have added an addEventListner to check for changes made to an autocomplete_light widget and submit selection automatically, rather than having to make the selection and then click a submit button.

Here is the form in my HTML template and the JavaScript I'm using to check for the change

```
<form novalidate id="select_form" class="contact_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="get" action="">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ query_form }}
   <div class="button_div">
    <button class="submit" type="submit">Search</button>
  </div>
</form>

<script>
var ac = document.getElementById('id_search-autocomplete');
ac.addEventListener("change", function(event){
    document.forms['select_form'].submit();
}, false);
</script>
```

This works fine if I select the autocomplate_light option by pressing 'Tab' or 'Enter' when the selection is highlighted. If I check the views.py dispatch method in the ClassBasedView I'm using I can see the following.

```
(Pdb) self.request.GET
<QueryDict: {u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'TwjMM4YsqBnRwFDVIbo68rP63l1nFScC'], 
             u'search': [u'133'], 
             u'search-autocomplete': [u'rover']}>
```

My problem is that mouse-clicking the highlighted selection does not populate the QueryDict object with the 'search' value.

```
(Pdb) self.request.GET
<QueryDict: {u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'TwjMM4YsqBnRwFDVIbo68rP63l1nFScC'], 
             u'search-autocomplete': [u'rover']}>
```

Here is my views.py file in which I'm setting the pdb trace.

views.py

```
class ClubIndexView(ListView):
    template_name = 'club_list.html'
    model = Club
    paginate_by = 10
    form_class = ClubForm

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ClubIndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['query_form'] = self.form_class
        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Club.objects.order_by('name_slug')

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        pdb.set_trace()
        # I'm checking self.request.GET here                   <<<<<<<<
        try:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('club_detail', args=[self.request.GET['search']]))
        except Exception, e:
            print "Error: {0}".format(e)
        return super(ClubIndexView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

I'd really appreciate any insight into why mouse-clicking does not add the required 'search' to the QueryDict object.

Thanks.

**Update 2014.07.23**

So I don't know if this is best practise but reading through autocomplete.js and fiddling around with the choices object I managed to get this working:

JS in my HTML template

```
<script>
$('#id_search-autocomplete').bind(
    'selectChoice',
    function(e, choice, autocomplete) {
        console.log(choice[0].getAttribute('data-value'))
        var ac = document.getElementById('id_search-autocomplete');
        ac.value = choice[0].getAttribute('data-value')
        document.forms['select_form'].submit();
    }
);
</script>
```

Views.py

```
def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('club_detail', args=[self.request.GET['search-autocomplete']]))
    except Exception, e:
        print "Error: {0}".format(e)
    return super(ClubIndexView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```